# How to add a desktop shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts, .desktop

How to add a file shortcut on the desktop in 16.04?
I tried to drag & drop a file from Nautilus to the desktop and nothing happened.

Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+C (in `/usr/share/applications`) / Ctrl+V on the Desktop. It is a dupe, I will look it up...

Comment: That is for an app I suppose but for a libreoffice document for example, how do I add a shorcut ? Note I can't get a menu when I right clic on the desktop ?

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. will post an answer if I cannot find a quick dupe.

Comment: Hi dupont, posted my answer. Please let me know if you manage.

Comment: Hi dupont, could you mention if works from cli? If it does, I need to know how to edit the answer to make it work from GUI as well. As mentioned in my answer, it should work normally as described.

Comment: what is cli ?  Previous answers were deleted so i'm lost.

Comment: cli = command line; the command `ln -s <source_file> <targeted_directory>`

Comment: sorry but that's too complicated. Why can't I simply drag & drop a shorcut to the desktop ???

Comment: Would be useful if you *mentioned* if it would work, like I asked multiple times, not to use it, but as an indication what the cause is :( I don't think this is going anywhere however.